# Avoiding define macro when making a lot of similar method calls

Tags: c++, legacy-code

The code below uses the `#define` macro. I'd like to avoid this but I don't see a way that uses C++ features *and* is more readable. The code is for testing a class `ClassUnderTest` that merges two instances of `PoorLegacyClass` into one. This `PoorLegacyClass` has many getters and setters and for testing purposes I need to call a lot of setters (or do I?).

In short, instead of writing

```
a.setValueX(20);
b.setValueX(30);
```

I would like to write something like

```
set(a, b, ValueX, 20, 30);
// or
set<ValueX>(a, 20, b, 30);
// or even
set(a, b, &PoorLegacyClass::setValueX, 20, 30);
```

Here is code similar to the code I use at the moment:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include "ClassUnderTest.h"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(Test_ClassUnderTest);

#define SETTER_A_B(fieldname, valueA, valueB)\
        a.set##fieldname(valueA);\
        b.set##fieldname(valueB);

struct TestContext
{
    PoorLegacyClass a, b;
};

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(ClassUnderTest_meaningful_description1, TestContext)
{
    SETTER_A_B(ValueX, 20, 30);
    auto result = ClassUnderTest().merge(a, b);

    BOOST_TEST(20 == result.getValueX());
}

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(ClassUnderTest_meaningful_description2, TestContext)
{
    SETTER_A_B(ValueY, 21, 37);
    auto result = ClassUnderTest().merge(a, b);

    BOOST_TEST(21 + 37 == result.getValueY());
}

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(ClassUnderTest_meaningful_description3, TestContext)
{
    SETTER_A_B(ValueZ, 12, 83);
    auto result = ClassUnderTest().merge(a, b);

    BOOST_TEST(12 + 83 == result.getValueZ());
}

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(ClassUnderTest_meaningful_description4, TestContext)
{
    SETTER_A_B(ValueY, 212, 37);
    SETTER_A_B(ValueX, 20, 30);
    auto result = ClassUnderTest().merge(a, b);

    BOOST_TEST(a.getValueY() == result.getValueY());
}

// more test cases that are similar to those above

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END();
```

While I will refactor `PoorLegacyClass` in the future that is not the subject of this question. What I would like to know, though, is how to avoid using the `#define` macro.

Comment: Actually, the only thing that seem to be wrong with your macro is, that you do not pass `a` and `b` as parameters. I mean, if you can use `BOOST_...()` macros all over the place, why fret about a simple, locally defined function-like macro `SETTER(fieldname, a, valueA, b, valueB)`?

Comment: @cmaster So speaks the master of C ;-). And you're right, after posting the question this seemed a bit silly even to myself. But still, as some kind of advanced padawan of C++ I try to define as few macros by myself as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're willing to accept the syntax `set(a, b, &PoorLegacyClass::setValueX, 20, 30);`, implementing such a `set` should be easy:

```
template <class T>
void set(PoorLegacyClass &a, PoorLegacyClass &b, void (PoorLegacyClass::*setter)(T), T valForA, T valForB)
{
  (a.*setter)(valForA);
  (b.*setter)(valForB);
}
```

You could also make it so that the `valFor` parameters use `T` in a non-deduced context, so that `T` can only be deduced from the setter and implicit conversions happen on the values:

```
template <class T>
struct NonDeduced { using type = T; }

template <class T>
void set(PoorLegacyClass &a, PoorLegacyClass &b, void (PoorLegacyClass::*setter)(T), typename NonDeduced<T>::type valForA, typename NonDeduced<T>::type valForB)
```

Comment: I believe the call syntax would be `&PoorLegacyClass::setValueX` though

Comment: @Ap31 Of course; the eyes see what they expect instead of what's actually written...

Answer (score 1):

Both `set(a, b, ValueX, 20, 30)` or `set<ValueX>(a, 20, b, 30)` would require some kind of preprocessing to concatenate `"set"` and `"ValueX"` into a new term.

Personally I think a bit of preprocessor is better than a ton of boilerplate, but as @Angew said, you can easily go with the third option:

`set(a, b, &PoorLegacyClass::setValueX, 20, 30);`

The only thing I wanted to add is you can use variadic templates to make this work for an arbitrary amount of objects:

```
template<class T> void set(void (PoorLegacyClass::*setter)(T))
{}

template<class T, typename... Args> void set(void (PoorLegacyClass::*setter)(T), 
PoorLegacyClass& obj, T val, Args&&... args)
{
    (obj.*setter)(val);
    set(setter, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

The call syntax would slightly change in this case:

`set(&PoorLegacyClass::setValueX, a, 20, b, 30);`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

1. Use `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` to make a fusion sequence of your structure.
2. Then use the `fusion::at_c<N>` to access the Nth element and set it's value
3. Put a free function around the above to take the sequence and use the `at_c<N>` to access a member appropriately.

Should avoid the need for macros..